# Can you call a constructor for a base class to create a derived object?

Tags: c++

```
class class1 {
public:
    class1(int x);

};

class class2 : public class1 {
};
```

Can I do:

```
class2 my_class2(10);
```

Or do I have to define the constructor again for `class2` (even though it does exactly the same thing)?

Comment: `Can I do: class2 my_class2(10);` have you tried doing it?

Comment: @Yousaf, Yes. If i declare the constructor (with the same signature) in class2, i get a linking error (undefined reference) and if I do not, It says it cant find a matching constructor. It seems quite dirty to have to define the same constructor multiple times, especially as in my real code there are many classes deriving from class1. Is this really the way to do it?

Comment: @liliscent So just to be clear: in the implementation file I would have 2 identical constructors, one for `class1::class1(int x)` and one for `class2::class2(int x)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since C++11 constructors can be inherited:

```
class class2 : public class1 {
public:
    using class1::class1;
};
```

Otherwise you have to do the following:

```
class class2 : public class1 {
public:
    class2(int x): class1(x) {}
};
```

A constructor of the base class has to be called anyway when constructing an object of the derived class.

Answer (score 3):

Since C++17, you can directly call public base-class constructors via [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) - without adding any code to the classes:

```
class2 my_class2{2}; // Note the curly braces!
```